# Dynamic IBOutlet to display Image

Tags: swift, iboutlet

I am trying to set IBoutlet to display current playing album art. This is what I have so far but no dice.

```
@IBOutlet weak var nowPlayingArtBackground: UIImageView!

    func currentArt() -> UIImage? {
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    @IBOutlet = currentArt()
```

Comment: What is your function supposed to be doing exactly? I also see you're missing a closing `}`.

Comment: I am trying to create a function to display currently playing album artwork. and Update when album or artist changes.

Comment: I think you're looking for `nowPlayingArtBackground.image = currentArt() `

Comment: I'm going to be blunt with you, it doesn't seem like you know what you are doing at all, it seems to me like you're throwing things at the wall to see if they stick and that's not gonna get you far if you're learning to program. I would strongly suggest you start over with some basic tutorials to get an idea of what everything is and how it works together. While I admire dfd's attempt to help you below, I believe you're missing some critical knowledge required for programming. Good luck.

Comment: I start class in two weeks. I gave myself a starter project based on a tutorial. I completely agree with your assessment EmilioPelaez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some things in your code - particularly `@IBOutlet = currentArt()` that makes it hard to understand *how* you think the code will work. So let's try starting at a high level.

You need a `UIImageView` (we'll call it `nowPlayingArtBackground`) that will display a piece of artwork (say, the output of a function called `currentArt`). SO far, so good with what you have. Using `@IBOutlet` suggests you're setting this all up in a Storyboard - good.

If you want the output of `currentArt()` to be viewed in `nowPlayingArtBackground`, the line of code you want is:

```
nowPlayingArtBackground.image = currentArt()
```

This will take the output from your function and display it. But there's two questions you haven't really answered:

**(1) Where is the output from `currentArt()` coming from?**

Your function code is code taking the contents of a `UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()`, but exactly what *is* this context? Generally speaking, album artwork is stored someplace, be it a database (Firebase?) or a file (locally? cloud?) - as it is, you haven't necessarily *defined* this.

**(2) What triggers changing the artwork displayed?**

In other words, what triggers a call to `currentArt()`.

Let's say you have your artwork stored locally as data in a database with the *key* being song/artist. You need a "driver" probably some AV stream (I'm really no expert on audio, but I only mean it's the "music player" that needs to drive things). When the song changes, you need to set the image to be the output of `currentArt()`, and you need to properly code the function to call up the artwork for that song/artist combination.

Hopefully some of this get you pointed in the right direction - or at least shows you some of the things missing in your question. Good luck!